# Set CSS custom properties through Object.assign

Tags: javascript, css, css-variables

I'm trying to update CSS custom properties ("CSS variables") through JavaScript. This works:

```
element.style.setProperty("--foo", "bar");
element.style.setProperty("--bar", "foo");
element.style.setProperty("border", "10px solid hotpink");
```

But using `Object.assign` doesn't work. The border gets applied, but not the CSS variables `--foo` and `--bar`.

```
const styles = {}

styles["--foo"] = "bar";
styles["--bar"] = "foo";
styles["border"] = "10px solid hotpink";

Object.assign(element.style, styles);
```

Anybody know what's wrong here?

Comment: to reduce the problem, even `element.style["--foo"] = "bar"` will not work

Comment: I suppose the reason why is because the `style` object itself contains [whitelisted, recognized CSS properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Properties_Reference), like `border`. When you are attempting to assign a non-valid CSS property (e.g. CSS custom property), then it will not be set. You need to set it using `.setProperty()` instead.

Comment: Go through this [MDN web docs - HTMLElement.style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)

Comment: Here's a way to do this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/8kqap1dn/ (the key is to iterate over the `styles` object and apply each property using `.setProperty`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the `element.style` object is a convenience object for mapping styles, but it's not the "real CSS".

As per Amelia's comment, all spec-defined css properties have predefined getters/setters on the `style` object, but this is (necessarily) not the case for custom properties. As such, the only way to properly trigger what needs to happen is through the getProperty/setProperty mechanism.

Comment: The need to use `setProperty()` for custom properties is the same on any CSSStyleDeclaration object, regardless of whether it's from `element.style` or in any other part of the CSSOM. The issue is, as you say up front, that CSS property declarations are not simple JS object properties, they need getters/setters to have an effect & only recognized CSS properties have them defined, as spec'd in [these CSSOM partial interfaces](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom/#dom-cssstyledeclaration-cssfloat).

Comment: `style["background-image"] = ...` [does work, actually](http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/js/live-dom-viewer/saved/7482), and is specified in CSSOM as ["dashed attribute"](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom/#dom-cssstyledeclaration-dashed-attribute).